# If $x = \frac{1 - \cos^2t}{\cos t}$ and $y = \frac{1-\cos^{2n}t}{\cos^nt}$ find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Tags: derivatives, parametric

This is the given question and I have to prove $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 = \frac{n^2(y^2+4)}{x^2+4}$.

Please help me solve this, I need it ASAP.

I have tried, but I couldn't do it

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc48c.jpg)

Comment: Man i really need the answer asap pls help

Comment: do you know about parametric differentiation

Comment: Yup i tried but couldn't do pls help

Comment: Can you provide the full ans

Comment: if you show your attempt i will .

Comment: Guys can anyone send the full proof

Comment: @LipunPanda Man, this is not a "do-my-homework" site.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

$$x^2=(\sec t- \cos t)^2=(\sec t+ \cos t)^2-4~~~~(1)$$
And $$y^2=(sec^n t- \cos^n t)^2=(\sec^{n}t+\cos^{n} t)^2-4~~~~(2)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}= n\tan t(\sec^{n} t+ \cos^{n} t) ~~~(3)$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\tan t~(\sec t+\cos t)$$
So $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}= n \left(\frac{\sec^n t+ \cos^n t}{\sec t+ \cos t}\right)$$
$$\implies  \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=n^2 \left(\frac{\sec^n t+ \cos^n t}{\sec t+ \cos t}\right)^2= n^2 \frac{y^2+4}{x^2+4}$$

For OP: $$\frac{dy}{dt}=n \sec^{n-1} t ~\sec t \tan t+ n \cos^{n-1} t~ \sin t= n \tan t~ (\sec ^n t+ \cos^n t)$$

Comment: How did you get dy/dt

Comment: See the last line of my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}=\frac{\dot y(t)}{\dot x(t)}.$$